# Error when deleting a row from a JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, indexoutofboundsexception

I have a `JTable` connected to a database and a Delete button here is my code

Filling the table with data:

```
static class inventoryTableItems{
    Object tempRow[];
    public static DefaultTableModel itemTableModel;

    inventoryTableItems() throws SQLException{
        getItems();
    }
    public void getItems() throws SQLException{
        try {
            itemTableModel = new DefaultTableModel(MainFramePanels.inventory_Panels.data, MainFramePanels.inventory_Panels.Columns);
            connectDB();
            rows = stmtUpd.executeQuery("select c.*, q.Qty from catalogue=c inner join Quantity=q on c.SKU = q.SKU");
            while(rows.next()){
                tempRow = new Object[]{rows.getString(1),rows.getString(2),rows.getString(3),rows.getString(4),rows.getFloat(5),rows.getInt(6)};
                itemTableModel.addRow(tempRow);
               }   
            MainFramePanels.inventory_Panels.itemTable.setModel(itemTableModel);
            MainFramePanels.mainFrame.pack();
            MainFramePanels.mainFrame.revalidate();
        }
        catch (SQLException e) {               
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        closeDB();
    }   
}
```

Here is the delete method code:

```
static class delOldItem{
    delOldItem() throws SQLException{
        delItem();
    }

    public static void delItem() throws SQLException{
        String Oprt = "DELETE"; 
        String Dscrpt = ("Delete TYPE("+tableItemType+") ITEM("+tableItemItem+") SKU("+tableItemSKU+") SIZE("+tableItemSize+") Thick("+tableItemThick+")");
        try {
            connectDB();
            successPanel = new JPanel();
            stmtUpd.executeUpdate("DELETE from catalogue where UPPER(SKU)=UPPER('"+tableItemSKU+"')");
            getLog(Username,Oprt,Dscrpt,null);
            new Log();

            UIManager.put("OptionPane.okButtonText", "OK");
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(successPanel,"SUCCESSFUL", "DELETE", JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION);
            new inventoryTableItems();
        }
        catch (SQLException e) {               
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        closeDB();
    }
}
```

When I delete a row it gives me an error.. what line is not correct? so that I will not have an error.

This is the error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
at java.util.Vector.elementData(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Vector.elementAt(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel.getValueAt(Unknown Source)
at prgrm.MainFramePanelsAction$1.valueChanged(MainFramePanelsAction.java:36)
at javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.fireValueChanged(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.fireValueChanged(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.fireValueChanged(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.setLeadSelectionIndex(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JTable.clearSelectionAndLeadAnchor(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JTable.tableChanged(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JTable.setModel(Unknown Source)
at prgrm.Query$inventoryTableItems.getItems(Query.java:126)
at prgrm.Query$inventoryTableItems.<init>(Query.java:115)
at prgrm.Query$delOldItem.delItem(Query.java:272)
at prgrm.Query$delOldItem.<init>(Query.java:257)
at prgrm.MenuBarActions$ToolBar$1.actionPerformed(MenuBarActions.java:390)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
    Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
at java.util.Vector.elementData(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Vector.elementAt(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel.getValueAt(Unknown Source)
at prgrm.MainFramePanelsAction$1.valueChanged(MainFramePanelsAction.java:36)
at javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.fireValueChanged(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.fireValueChanged(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.setValueIsAdjusting(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableUI$Handler.setValueIsAdjusting(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableUI$Handler.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: in what line? where are you deleting/? but probably is that you are using incorrect index try to use `jtable.convertRowIndexToModel(..)`

Comment: @nachokk im deleting a row that I selected on the table.. when i delete it, it gave me an error which is outofbounds but when i check my database it was deleted.. so i want to solve the error that it gives me

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @John follow andrew advice, for better help sooner post a sscce... "static class" that only is possible for nested classes, i can't understand your problem, you should follow java code name conventions

Comment: My codes are already too long and its connected to different java files... I'll just ask a question.. I think im having an error on my Model or Jtable... will there be an error if I updated the database and just rerun the function that will fill up the JTable without the firetablerow?

Comment: Use proper Java naming conventions. Class names should start with an upper case character (ie. InventorTableItems). Although I even have a question why this is a class. It should just be a method that you invoke. Given that you have static classes and variables all over you code I would say you have a bad design on your code. Get rid of the static classes and variables.

Answer (score 0):

in delItem() function, move the position of following after closeDB() call.

```
new inventoryTableItems();
```

Hope it will help.